# why is my jsonformat passing on a null value?

Tags: android, ios, geolocator

**Exception in console:The method '[]' was called on null after trying to print data from api using jsonformat
I tried making an if check so that i can assign the temperature to 0 and assign the jsondata to it using setState to change it but it also didnt work.Please i need help and any contribution will be appreciated.Thank you

```
//this is the code am using to print the data

 import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:untitled14/utilities/constants.dart';
    
    class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
       final locationData;
    
    
       LocationScreen({required this.locationData}); // LocationScreen({required this.locationData});
    
      @override
      _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
    }
    
    class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
      int? temperature;
      int? conditions;
      String? message;
       String? cityName;
    
    
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        updateUI(widget.locationData);
      }
      void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
        setState(() {
          if (weatherData == null) {
            temperature = 0;
          }
          double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
          temperature=temp.toInt();
          // cityName = weatherData['name'];
          // conditions = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
    
          print(temperature);
        });
      }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:SpinKitSpinningCircle(
          color:Colors.blue,
          size: 100,
        )
      ),
      // body: Center(
      //   child: ElevatedButton(
      //     onPressed: () {
      //       // getLocation();
      //       //Get the current location
      //     },
      //     child: Text('Get Location'),
      //   ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}




//this is the api 
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    
    class NetworkHelper{
    
      final String url;
    
    
      NetworkHelper({required this.url});
    
      Future getData()async{
    
        http.Response response=await http.get(Uri.parse(url)
        );
        if(response.statusCode==200){
          String data=response.body;
    
    
          return jsonDecode(data);
        }
        else{
          print(response.statusCode);
        }
    
      }
    
    
    }


//this code tries to open our LoadingScreen after the SpinningCircle is over
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:untitled14/screens/location_screen.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:untitled14/services/location.dart';
    import 'package:untitled14/services/networking.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
    
    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
    }
    @override
    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
        double? latitude;
        double? longitude;
        var weatherData;
      //
      // var newdata;
    
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getLocationData();
    
        Timer(
    
    
            Duration(seconds: 3),()=>
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
              return LocationScreen(locationData: weatherData,);
            }))
        );
        // getData();
      }
    
      void getLocationData() async {
        Location mylocation = Location();
        await mylocation.getCurrentLocation();
        latitude = mylocation .latitude;
        longitude = mylocation.longitude;
    
        NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(url:
            'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1');
         weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    
      }
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child:SpinKitSpinningCircle(
              color:Colors.blue,
              size: 100,
            )
          ),
          // body: Center(
          //   child: ElevatedButton(
          //     onPressed: () {
          //       // getLocation();
          //       //Get the current location
          //     },
          //     child: Text('Get Location'),
          //   ),
          // ),
        );
      }
    }
//getting user requestpermission

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class Location{
  // uncomment this
   double? latitude;
   double? longitude;



Future<void> getCurrentLocation()async{
try{
  LocationPermission permission=await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  Position position=await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  latitude=position.latitude;
  longitude=position.longitude;
}
catch(e){
print(e);}
}

}**
```

Answer (score 0):

This should print the correct value :

```
  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        temperature = 0;
      } else {
        double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
        temperature = temp.toInt();
        // cityName = weatherData['name'];
        // conditions = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      }
      print(temperature);
    });
  }
```

Comment: yeah but it prints an exception

Comment: could you show the result of printing weatherData ?

Comment: But i need the actual data from the api so that i can Update the UI with it

Comment: Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 2,557ms.
I/flutter ( 5011): 0

Comment: thats is the result

Comment: Anything unusual?